# Basic UI Gtk with XML interfaces

Tags: c, xml, gtk

I'm testing some GTK+ examples.

At some given function, a reference to some path of a XML file appears in
C code. It explains that the code in C is reading the XML content to
later compile it to be usable from the C code:

```
static void
example_app_window_class_init (ExampleAppWindowClass *class)
{
  gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource (GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (class),
                                               "/org/gtk/exampleapp/window.ui");
}
```

I can understand what is happening here, but not **how is it reading the source XML?** `window.ui`, in this case. Because the repo has no folder
as they mention (`/org/gtk/exampleapp/`).

So, in my function I expect to do something like:

```
static void my_style_window_class_init(MyStyleWindowClass *class) {
  gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource(GTK_WIDGET_CLASS(class),
                                              "window.ui");
}
```

All my XML content is in the same folder as `*.c` and `*.h` files. This is a *testing* decision and have no other meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_from_resource()` part of the function name indicates that the path `/org/gtk/exampleapp/window.ui` is not a filesystem path, but rather a resource path. Resource paths tie into a feature of GLib called [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GResource.html) which allows you to embed binary data inside a program or shared library.

You would write an XML file to describe what local files map to what resource paths, and then as part of your build process, you would convert that to a C source file with the `glib-compile-resources` tool. You then build that C source file into your program. The full details are on the page that I linked in the first paragraph.

(Note that these are not the same as the embedded resources in Windows executables, which use a different technology altogether, but work in similar ways.)

If you want to load something from a file, GLib and GTK+ and other libraries built on them provide a `_from_file()`, `_from_data()`, or `_from_stream()` alternative to the `_from_resource()` function. `_from_file()` reads the data from a file directly. `_from_data()` reads from memory. `_from_stream()` reads from a GStream, which is an object-oriented I/O endpoint defined by GLib in its GIO module. The function name suffix is optional; it varies.

In the case of `gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource()`, the equivalent provided is [`gtk_widget_class_set_template()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-class-set-template), which follows the `_from_data()` pattern of reading from memory. The memory is stored in a [GBytes](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Byte-Arrays.html) object, so you have to read from your local file into the GBytes.

Comment: So its a kind of `virtual path` only available within the `resource` wrap _scope_ ¿correct? The documentation says to use `Java-style-path` to avoid conflicts. What kind of conflicts? I think it is something to do with the local _HD_ path, but i think i'm not understanding completely.

Comment: Yes, it is a virtual path, with an entirely fresh namespace. The reason why it's saying to avoid conflicts is because if you have a resource named `/myresource.xml` and one of your shared libraries also tries to have a resource named `/myresource.xml` there will be a conflict.

Comment: Thanks,  i think i'm  better understanding.

Comment: @Hell0 do you still need help?

Comment: thx, i'm setting up docs, so the next weeks i will do that. But thank you any way. Apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's an oldie and the question seems answered but I'd like to take a direct approach and place solution - turns out that we can substitute this line

```
gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource (widget_class,
                         "/org/gnome/gtksourceview/tests/ui/test-widget.ui");
```

with this line to make the code work.

```
if (g_file_get_contents("test-widget.ui", &contents, &len, &err) == FALSE)
    g_error("error reading test-widget.ui: %s", err->message);
bytes = g_bytes_new_take(contents, len);
gtk_widget_class_set_template(GTK_WIDGET_CLASS(klass), bytes);
```